# IsDefault and IsDefaulted properties

Tags: c#, xaml

Can you please explain me what do these two properties?

`Button.IsDefault` and `Button.IsDefaulted`

I tried to run the example on MSDN but it works.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.isdefault(v=vs.110).aspx

I should create a method?

Can you make me two simple example please?

Answer (score 2):

IsDefault can be got or set, to make the button the default when enter is pressed.

IsDefaulted is the ReadOnly property that shows if the button is default. This is used in the code behind.

For example, if you want your button to be the default button for the form, use

```
<Button Name="btn_whatever" IsDefault="True"/>
```

Then you can do in the C#

```
if(btn_whatever.IsDefaulted)
    //do something
```

or

```
if(btn_whatever.IsDefault)
    //do something
```